# How to access the individual values form a dictionary, if the values are in list of lists format?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested-lists

I have written a config file in json for my test function. The config file looks like this :

```
{

    "Chrome_executable_path": "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\PycharmProjects\\chromedriver.exe",
    "File_locations": [["C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupAge8277.csv"],
        ["C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupAge8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupArea8277.csv"],
        ["C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupAge8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupArea8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupEthnic8277.csv"],
        ["C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupAge8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupArea8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupEthnic8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupSex8277.csv"],
        ["C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupAge8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupArea8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupEthnic8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupSex8277.csv", "C:\\Users\\AIGHOSH\\Desktop\\DQ_DATA\\DimenLookupYear8277.csv"]
    ],
    "Null_values": [["_"], ["@"], ["<>"], ["-"], ["#"]],
    "Operation": [["None"], ["Append"], ["Merge"], ["Append then Merge"]],
    "weights": [
        {
        "completeness": "0.2",
        "timeliness": "0.2",
        "uniqueness": "0.2",
        "validity": "0.2",
        "integrity": "0.2"
    },
        {
    "completeness": "0.1",
    "timeliness": "0.3",
    "uniqueness": "0.2",
    "validity": "0.2",
    "integrity": "0.2"
    },
        {
    "completeness": "0.2",
    "timeliness": "0.2",
    "uniqueness": "0.3",
    "validity": "0.1",
    "integrity": "0.2"
    },
        {
    "completeness": "0.2",
    "timeliness": "0.2",
    "uniqueness": "0.1",
    "validity": "0.4",
    "integrity": "0.1"
    },
        {
    "completeness": "0.1",
    "timeliness": "0.1",
    "uniqueness": "0.4",
    "validity": "0.2",
    "integrity": "0.2"
    }
    ]
}
```

Now I want value[0] to be my first test case parameter, then v[1] to be my second test case parameter.

my test case function :

```
   #for the fist element of the values(eg: v[0])
   def test_case(self): 
     self.dqopenPage = DqOpenPage(self.driver)    
     self.dqopenPage.drop(filess = config["File_locations"]) #should take the first list with only 1 file
     self.dqopenPage.df_operation(operation=config["Operations"]) #should take the "None"
     self.dqopenPage.define_null_value(null = config["Null_values"])#should take "_"
```

So how to fetch the values using a for loop and run the test case function for all the corresponding values like v[1], v[2], etc.

Comment: do you want to test with all the index-0 elements, then all the index-1, ... or with any combinations of indexes?

Comment: To me, it is not really clear what you want to do? What should v[1] actually be? I dont think your code actually needs the DqOpenPage stuff, is that a library?

Comment: @gimix yes exactly that!! : test with all the index-0 elements, then all the index-1, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the individual values in here like this,

```
print(config["File_locations"][0][0])
print(config["Null_values"][0][0])
print(config["Operation"][0][0])
```

If you want to access individual values with a loop  you can do this

This is the way to loop through the File locations.

```
for file in config["File_locations"]:
    for index in range(len(file)):
        print(file[index])
```

This is the way to loop through the Null values or the Operations,

```
for value in config["Null_values"]:
    print(value[0])
```

I didn't really understand what lists you wanted to loop through but I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**decoding json**

```py
#cfg = (your config file)
jcfg=json.loads(cfg)
```

**testing with all index-0 parameters, then all index-1, ...**

```py
for testno in range(5):
    print(f'\t\t\tindex {testno}')
    for floc in jcfg['File_locations'][testno]:
        nv = jcfg['Null_values'][testno]
        op = jcfg['Operation'][testno]
        w = jcfg["weights"][testno]
        print(f'testing for {floc}, {nullv}, {op}, {w}')
```

You get 1 test for `testno = 0` (the one `floc`, with `nv = "_"` and `op = None`), then 2 tests for `testno = 1` and so on

**testing with each parameter permutation**

```py
#jcfg['File_locations'] = (just one list with all your files)

for i_floc, i_nv, i_op, i_w in itertools.permutations(range(5), 4):
        floc = jcfg['File_locations'][i_floc]
        nv = jcfg['Null_values'][i_nv]
        op = jcfg['Operation'][i_op]
        w = jcfg['weights'][i_w]
        print(f'testing for {floc}, {nullv}, {op}, {w}')
```

You get all the 5! possible permutations of parameters

Note: To test this I replaced `\\` with `/` in your 'File_locations` to avoid escape issues.